# maximising static IPs in google-compute-hosted microservices

Tags: google-compute-engine, devops

My first time I have *asked* a question on here.

I have an expanding set of services hosted on google compute platform.
The initial round was set up in a very stressed situation, and I am now refactoring.
I currently have 3 **EDIT: no thats 4** microservice VM hosts, which will all be HTTPS soon (and so need their own IP). In addition a list of test boxes, as we are developing bits.  Test boxes do not need https.

- question 1) Does any one have a work-round to get multiple static IPs per host?  This is why i have large numbers of hosts.
- question 2) How can I have more than a /29 of static IPs (eg 8 or more). This is corporate work, we will pay for services.
- question 3) According to [google api](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/), I may deallocate static IPs.  I cannot find an implementation for this. Do you know of one?  As I have built systems like this in the past; I know there is no technical reason why there should not be an API for this.
- Bonus Q, Question 4) Is there a mechanism to serialise a saved harddisk out of google cloud?  This would make my CEO happy.

An **ideal response is a relevent "Fine Manual" to read.**
I work on GMT time.  All linux hosts, probably not relevant.  Although a developer, I can admin most things Linux.

UPDATE: if you delete an IP  via `gcloud compute addresses delete $name --region europe-west1` but don't delete the IF inside the box, this makes it not static. Which is the objective of Q3.

Comment: Or is it possible to copy disks between user accounts, as 8 fixed IPs will have scaling issues soon as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answers to your question below:

1. Its directly not possible to assign multiple IPs to an instance. One workaround to achieve this is to create [multiple forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules) rules pointing to the same target pool with that instance.
2. Its currently not possible to reserve the whole block of IP addresses as the address are randomly assigned to the instances from the pool of IPs available.
3. If you have reserved static IPs in your project you can can release that IP from one instance and assign it to another.
4. There is no direct way to that, however one workaround I can think of is to use [dd tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) to clone your disk as .raw and save that to cloud storage. This clone case be used to create other disks outside your project.

I hope that helps.

Comment: RE q1, as boxes are cheap; this isn't a large concern.